# Python Serialisation c# Deserialisation

Tags: c#, python, serialization, marshalling

I have python server that serialize some dictionary by using the [`marshal` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html). And send serialized message to the c# client socket. How I can deserialize this message on the client (c#) side. I can not use IronPython because of problems with the speed of execution.

Or do you know other ways to serialize/deserialize "messages" between Python and c#.

Comment: You should be using WCF for interoperability.

Comment: What speed of execution problems?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams This program should be executed in 3 seconds. And IronPython module execution add 1-3 extra seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about JSON?  You could write, or maybe even find, a de-Python-pickle-er for C#, but something like a dict is easy to represent in JSON, and that's a well known, well defined standard for which reliable, fast serilaize/deserialize libraries exist in nearly every language.  There's also XML of course, but JSON's usually easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

`marshal` is generally Python-specific. If you want cross-language support then you should use [`json`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

[YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaml) support is available in many [languages](http://www.yaml.org/) and supports many data types [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation) syntax is a subset of YAML version 1.2 and also enjoys wide-spread support.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `marshal`, "protocol buffers" has good support in both python and c#. Google provide the python implementation, and there are multiple c# implementations. Protocol buffers offers excellent versioning support, a rich variety of cross platform implementations, and very efficient serialization, ideal for fast binary socket usage.